# hsqldb.jar migration - ClientSocketConfiguraton inner interface not present in HSLSocketFactory.java

Tags: java, hsqldb

I am migrating hsqldb.jar from version 1.7.1 to 2.4.0. HSqlSocketfactory class doesn't contain inner interface ClientSocketConfigurator and method setSocketConfigurator(ClientSocketConfigurator socketConfigurator). Can anyone please help me with alternative of this method? My Code is :-

```
HsqlSocketFactory.getInstance(false).setSocketConfigurator(this);
HsqlSocketFactory.getInstance.setSocketConfigurator(this);
LogRepository.DATABASE.info("Configured connection on HsqlSocketFactory");
```